# Copy calendar event from the web version of calendar to macOS calendar

Tags: macos, ms-office, calendar

I have this Office 365 license for the company I work. One of the apps is the web version of calendar, or whatever it is called.

When I receive an invitation for a meeting through outlook for web, the event is added to the calendar inside the web suite.

I want to add the event to macOS iCal.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Doesn't adding Office365 account to Calendar deliver desired result?

Comment: no, the event is displayed only on MS Calendar.

Comment: I have corporate Microsoft 365 Business Premium account. Adding this account to Calendar makes associated calendar to appear. This is however, my account/personal calendar, but there are many-many other calendars available in Sharepoint/Teams (team/channel/site etc). So which calendar we are talking about?